# How to add data to listview after dialog which was called by notification?

Tags: java, android, listview

My goal is add data to listView, after push on notification shows dialog, if user press Yes, app will show activity with fragment, and again will display new dialog to add new item. But if I press add, I get:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager()' on a null object reference
```

My dialog to add new item to listview be in MainActivity, but I need to refresh my listview in Fragment, i am using ViewPager.

It seems like my fragment not initialized yet, but dialog at display now. How to implement this solution? One more thing, in my notification I set AutoCancel(true), but notif is still being on screen.

Here is the screen chronology:
[Step 1](http://iscr.ru/photo/1433956892_uvedomlenie.PNG)
[Step 2](http://iscr.ru/photo/1433956971_dialog.PNG)

one more image i can't add(

My dialog activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final String text = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");

    new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.title_alert)
            .setMessage(R.string.title_alert)
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(DialogActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("notification",true);
                    intent.putExtra("text",text);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            }).show();
}
```

My method which will cal if user press add item in second dialog

```
 private void showTrackerDialog(TrackersFragment f, final String text,boolean isFromNotif) {
    final TrackersFragment trackersFragment = f;
    tracker = new Tracker();
    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title("New tracker :)")
            .customView(R.layout.add_track, true)
            .positiveText("ADD")
            .positiveColorRes(R.color.primary_light_green)
            .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
            .negativeColorRes(R.color.primary_red)
            .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPositive(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                    if (hours.getValue() == 0 && minutes.getValue() == 0 && isLimit.isCheck()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your the input values!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    //limited
                    if ((((hours.getValue() != 0 && minutes.getValue() == 0) || (hours.getValue() == 0 && minutes.getValue() != 0))
                            || (hours.getValue()!=0 && minutes.getValue()!=0)) && isLimit.isCheck()) {
                        try {
                            hoursToMillis = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(hours.getValue()));
                            minutesToMillis = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(minutes.getValue()));
                            tracker.setLimitTime((hoursToMillis * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (minutesToMillis * 60 * 1000));
                            tracker.setName(name.getText().toString());
                            tracker.setElapsedTime((long) 0);
                            tracker.setIsFinished(false);
                            tracker.persist(RemindMe.db);
                            trackersFragment.updateListView(true,tracker);
                            return;
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something goes wrong :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    //no limit
                    if (!isLimit.isCheck()) {
                        tracker.setLimitTime(0L);
                        tracker.setName(name.getText().toString());
                        tracker.setElapsedTime((long) 0);
                        tracker.setIsFinished(false);
                        tracker.persist(RemindMe.db);
                        trackersFragment.updateListView(true,tracker);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNegative(MaterialDialog dialog) {
                }
            }).build();
```

And here is the NullPointerExeption, `getSupportLoaderManager()`

```
 public void updateListView(boolean isAdded,Tracker tracker) {
    if(isAdded && tracker!=null){
        trackerList.add(tracker);
       getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(TRACKLOADER_ID).forceLoad();
        adapter.swapCursor(Tracker.getAll(db));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here isn't trying to add to the list, but understanding the lifecycle. It seems to me that you have not setup the fragment, or possible have crossed paths of which fragment library you are using. Your error says `v4.Support.Fragment`. Make sure you use that same class everywhere. Even when opening it. (Check your imports. Make sure they are all v4).

Also check that your `MainActivity` does not extend `Activity`, but `FragmentActivity`

After which, If you are trying to notify your app from a notification, your best solution is going to be a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: I thinked about it, but could this approach lead to the same issue, because in my MainActivity i have 3 fragments, listview which i must refresh be in second fragment(1 position of viewpager)?